# How can my translation be shown in my website

Tags: python, css, django, translation

I am currently working on my website, which is a translator which you input a phrase and it gets translated into an invented language.

Here's the code of the translator function:

```
def translator(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.lower() in "a":
            if letter.isupper:
                translation = translation + "U"
            else:
                translation = translation + "u"
        elif letter.lower() in "t":
            if letter.isupper:
                translation = translation + "A"
            else:
                translation = translation + "a"
        elif letter.lower() in "c":
            if letter.isupper:
                translation = translation + "G"
            else:
                translation = translation + "g"
        elif letter.lower() in "g":
            if letter.isupper:
                translation = translation + "C"
            else:
                translation = translation + "c"
    return translation
```

However, I am stuck in showing this funcion in my web, here's the code in views.py:

```
from .translate import translator

def translator_view(request):
    
    return render(request,'main/translator.html')

def translated_view(request):
    text = request.GET.get('text')
    print('text:', text)
    translate = translator
    dt = translator.detect(text)
    tr = translated.text
    context = {
        'translated': tr
    }
    return render(request, context, 'main/translated.html')
```

Here's the template where you introduce the text:

```
<form action="{% url 'translated' %}" method= "get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <center><h2 class = "display-3">TRANSLATE YOUR DNA CHAIN</h2></center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="6"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type='Submit' class= "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Translate</button>
    
    </div>   
</form>
```

Here's the template that should would show the translation.

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

{% block content%}

<div>
    <center><h2 class="display-4">DNA TRANSLATED SUCCESFULLY INTO</h2></center>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>
        {{ translated }}
    </h3>
</div>   

{% endblock content%}
```

Comment: why add ```in``` in ```letter.lower() in "a"``` instead of ==?

Comment: so it can be shown in  uppercase and lowercase